# how to solve react native UI login problem "This server only accepts HTTPS requests"

Tags: react-native, abp, openiddict

I create MVC template & react native

I do all steps in [Getting-Started-React-Native](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Getting-Started-React-Native)
but when I want to login in react native app I get this error

```
The response was successfully returned as a JSON document: {
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "This server only accepts HTTPS requests.",
  "error_uri": "https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2083"
}
```

how can solve this problem?
how to config OpenIddict to accept http requests?

Comment: In this section here: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Getting-Started-React-Native?Tiered=No#how-to-configure-run-the-backend , what happens if you change all these http to https urls?

Comment: because of self sign certificate mobile app can't connect to server

Comment: How about if you add this in your configuration of OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreBuilder:
`builder.DisableTransportSecurityRequirement();` ?

Answer (score 3):

For ABP.io with .net 6 and above and openIdDic

```
public override void PreConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
    {
        PreConfigure<OpenIddictBuilder>(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddValidation(options =>
            {
                options.AddAudiences("PaymentService");
                options.UseLocalServer();
                options.UseAspNetCore();
            });

//Below line needs to be added

                builder.AddServer(options => { options.UseAspNetCore().DisableTransportSecurityRequirement(); });
            });
        }
```